# Are these Spring/Hibernate entities good (performance-wise) for culinary app?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to store recipes and ingredients in db. I came up with these entities:

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String notes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<IngredientQuantity> ingredientQuantities = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ingredient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<IngredientQuantity> ingredientQuantities = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
public class IngredientQuantity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_recipe")
    private Recipe recipe;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_ingredient")
    private Ingredient ingredient;

    private double quantity;
}
```

Now when I want to create a new recipe, I would have to check every ingredient if they already exist in db or not. Is this approach any good? And if it is fine, do I make a one call to db to fetch all ingredients using "WHERE (...) IN ()" clause or hit db with multiple single queries?

Comment: Don’t ask opinion based questions - there is no good or bad entity, if it works it works and you will learn to write better code by practice  and through reading books. Also don’t worry about performance prematurely (premature optimization is actually anti pattern) you solve performance issue only after (and if) ever needed

Comment: @JAsgarov alright, thank you!